# WSARecv - обязан ли заполнить весь предоставленный буфер или нет?

Tags: winapi, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, из описания WSARecv - не понятно следующее:

Когда я вызываю WSARecv - ставя задачу на чтение приходящих данных и когда указываю указатель на буфер и его размер, то при условии, что кол-во Входящих байт равно или больше размера предоставленного буфера, то WSARecv обязан заполнить весь предоставленный ему буфер или может вернуть этот вызов только с частично заполненным буфером ?

Это я спрашиваю, потому что не совсем понятно, как тут действовать. Предположим я получаю то же html-тело, без заранее известно размера, то есть я вызываю WSARecv До тех пор, пока не получу признак конца html-тела, но вот, что непонятно:

-Я вызываю WSARecv c предоставленным буфером условно в 100 байт.

-Вызов вернулся, признака конца html-тела в полученных байтах нет.

-Я вызываю WSARecv опять, предварительно увеличив realloc`ом буфер еще + 100 байт и далее для WSARecv я должен предоставить указатель на адрес в моем буфере, с которого я хочу, чтобы WSARecv произвел запись принимаемых данных и вот тут и вопрос:

-Я должен ли я думать, что первый вызов WSARecv полностью заполним первые 100 байт принятыми данными или же часть из этих 100 байт, могут оказаться пустыми ?
И тогда при втором вызове WSAREcv, если я укажу указатель на первый элемент второй части выделенных 100 байт, то у меня не получится непрерывных принимаемых данных, а будут прорежены или мусором или нулями, если я буфер заранее занулил.

Comment: `WSARecv` вообще ничего не обязан заполнить.

Comment: @user7860670, ну я это условно написал, я конечно же имел ввиду, что заполнение буфера происходит после вызова WSARecv, а не сам WSARecv самолично заполняет буфер. Или Вы что то другое имели ввиду ?

Comment: ¿Ну а что тогда непонятного в его работе? Там везде четко оговорено, сколько он может принять, и каким образом узнать количество принятых байт.

Comment: Зачем вы ставите метки не относящиеся к вопросу? Вы ничего про язык си и си++ не спрашиваете, зачем тогда ставите?

Comment: @– こきん, прошу извинить, в следующий раз не буду.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо! Совсем забыл, что getqueuedcompletionstatus() возвращает кол-во прочитанных или переданных байт.